# Replacing variable in :url for wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have the following defintion in wicked pdf to render the footer

> ```
>    :footer => {:html => { :url => 'http://www.descher.at/test.html' },
> ```

What I want to do is to replace the values of [page] and [topage] as added in the
html to the real values.

Is this possible using the given reference :url, if yes, what is the correct way of embedding
the respective variable in the html to be embedded?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Adding the following function to the resp. html file leads to the required replacement.

```html
<html><head><script>
function subst() {
  var vars={};
  var x=window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
  for (var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
  var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
  for (var i in x) {
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
    for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
  }
}
</script></head><body style="border:0; margin: 0;" onload="subst()">
<table style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="section"></td>
    <td style="text-align:right">
      Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```